# Save Firebase bandwidth with offline capabilities enabled?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can someone explain how enabling Firebase offline capabilities affects bandwidth usage?

Let's say the user has only one client and all user data is kept synchronized:

```
FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
let userRef = FIRDatabase.database().referenceWithPath("user")
userRef.keepSynced(true)
```

All user data stored in Firebase has once been created by the user on this device and should have already been cached offline.

I would assume that once the data is synchronized with Firebase and the user re-opens their app, only little traffic would be necessary to check if the offline cache needs update resulting in less traffic.

Or is the opposite true and the traffic will be higher because all user data is downloaded when the app starts even if the server data is not newer than the client data?

Comment: I'm wondering the same. I have been looking on the internet for an answer on this, but can't find it.